# No callback with FB.ui

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I can't get the Facebook UI callback to run.  I've used the example from the FB dev site:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

```
FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri: 'YOUR URL HERE',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

When I run it on my site I get no callback
https://www.ipassexam.com/page/fb-test

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You have some error's in your site. The javascript console is showing that `FB` is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the redirect_uri parameter. This works for me every time:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',  
    link: "http://...",
    name: "Some Title",
    caption: "Some Caption",
    description: "Some Description",
    picture: "http://..."
}, function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
        alert('Post was not published.');
    }
});
```

Also make sure that there are no errors in the console. But i did not see any error anyway.

Comment: The damnedest thing.  I tried that earlier and removing the redirect_uri caused an error.  Just tried again and it worked this time.  

Thanks

Comment: @luschn after days of meddling, i found this helped alot, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Spent 2 hours figuring the problem and the solution is, mention the display property (popup in my case).

```
function postToFeed() {

// calling the API ...
var obj = {
  method: 'feed',
  **display: 'popup',**
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
  caption: 'Reference Documentation',
  description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
};

function callback(response) {
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
}

FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

}

Tip: redirect_uri is not mandatory if display is explicitly specified as popup.

Comment: It's helped me to post the link on fb

Answer (score 1):

Try to set display attribute with "popup" with the request as below:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',  
    link: "http://...",
    name: "Some Title",
    caption: "Some Caption",
    description: "Some Description",
    display: "popup",
    picture: "http://..."
}, function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
        alert('Post was not published.');
    }
});
```

I have encountered this issue inside the FB canvas page when I tried to post using feed method and I always got the "undefined" response. I have tried the above attribute and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try using an anonymous function as a callback -

```
FB.ui(obj, function(response) {
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
});
```

Comment: Changed to: 

    FB.ui(obj, function(){
              alert("Post ID: " + response['post_id']);
    });

but still no joy :(

Answer (score 0):

try to add this before `FB.init`

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() { //put FB.init here }

 (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document));
```

so that it will became like this

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APPID", status: true, cookie: true});
};

(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document));
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be not your case, but I was looking for a reason of a similar behaviour almost a week and finally I have found that FB.ui was trying to create the iframe to display on the page and for this was creating this iframe under div with id=fb-root.
Unfortunately, this div was inside another div which I myself made invisible! 
So - to cut the long story short - check if you have div with id=fb-root and if this div is visible