# Facebook Share Dialog href ignored in Page Tab app

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but this code:

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: 'https://www.google.com'
    }, function() {});
```

When invoked inside a Page Tab app, will produce this on my wall:

[image: Screenshot]

Which, when clicked, opens:

```
https://www.facebook.com/foo?sk=app_540256799412345&fb_action_ids=10152666136012345&fb_action_types=og.shares&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481212345
```

Why doesn't it go to `google.com` (specified in `href`)?

**My intention is to call Share Dialog from inside Page Tab app with its `href` containing `app_data`.** When somebody click the shared link, it will open the app, and by checking the presence of `app_data`, redirect to proper page, e.g. in pseudo-code:

```
index.server:
    if signed_request.app_data isnt empty
        redirect '/gallery?id=' + signed_request.app_data
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have `Stream post URL security` set to on in your app settings (under Settings -> Migrations)?

Comment: @CBroe nope, it's false, which I believe is the default.

Comment: Well then probably your parameter does not get passed correctly, or not handed over to the dialog correctly – so _check_ that.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are doing this using the open graph,I think you should provide the callback in the FB.api call try doing that, so when ever someone clicks on your post it will take them to that url.

```
FB.api(
          'me/objects/restaurant.restaurant',
          'post',
          {
            app_id: xxxxx[correctly used app id],
            type: "restaurant.restaurant",
            url:[try giving the call back url here],
            title: "Sample Restaurant",
           image:"https://static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png",
            description: "This place rocks",
            contact_info: "http://www.facebook.com",
            location: "-122.148283"
          },
          function(response) {
            // handle the response
          }
    );
```

But if you have to do using the FB.ui call please refer to this question i think it might be helpful
[No callback with FB.ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095146/no-callback-with-fb-ui)

Comment: That question you linked talks about `redirect_url` which I don't use. I'll try to use Open Graph and update this question. Thanks!